# Building a PHP forum, how to link to last post permalink in a paged thread

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I'm building a relatively simple PHP forum and trying to add in a few nice features from some of the mainstream boards like phpBB.

The database structure is the simple 3 table approach. Categories, threads and posts.

I'm implementing a 'last post' feature for each category and thread. I already have the last post information as this is stored in the DB, that isn't the problem. What I'm trying to work out is how to link to this post in a thread which has **paged** replies, say 25 per page. If my post is number 26 of 26 how would you program the thread to go to page two? Say I wanted to permalink to post 30 of 90, how might you link to page 2 and ensure the correct number of replies/pages are either side?

I've been trying to work out how phpBB do it, but I figure you could spend all year ripping that apart and get no where. I see they pass the post_id as an additional parameter with the thread_id, but I can't work out how they use that information. Any ideas for a starting point? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution based on what @aditya-menon and @GeoPhoenix have said. I know the total posts already, so I've just divided that by the posts per page to get the total number of pages. The last post will always been on the last page so that's easy enough.

The challenge is working out which page a post falls on in the middle of a thread. I've run a `BETWEEN` query like this to calculate how many posts into a thread a particular post is

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM posts 
WHERE topic_id = $TOPIC_ID AND post_id BETWEEN 0 AND $POST_ID
```

Then divide posts per page by this number and `ceil()` to give the page number the post is on.

Not so sure how efficient that query will be with a large forum but it seems to do the job. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how phpBB does this. But what I'd do is track of the last post by it's own ID. For each permalink request, I'd 'render' the thread internally (just the barebones, no need to even fetch the post information like body from the database). Just fetch the number of answers on the thread and do your usual logic of splitting it in pages.

From this, I can find out easily which page the last post is going into, rather than try to 'ensure' anything from my end (look at what the system is doing, don't try to bend it to your will) - then, of course, it's a relatively simple matter of redirecting to that page, and appending a HTML `anchor` id to the post and to the URL so the browser automatically scrolls to that post.

Well, that's off the top of my head. Mature systems might have solved it in a more elegant manner, please feel free to research and post back here :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example, rendering 5 posts at each page on a thread with 20posts

 Queries

```
// get the first 5 posts<br/>
SELECT posts FROM topics WHERE topicid = 1 LIMIT 0,5

// get the next five posts<br/>
SELECT posts FROM topics WHERE topicid = 1 LIMIT 5,10
```

on php side, page controls (first,next,previous,last) are form buttons which submit the form and location identifiers such as first page X , next page Y , previous page Z, last page S .. a url using GET method

http://example.com/forum/topic.php?id=1&cur=5&next=10&previous=5&last=20

this kind of information about tracking the user is in topic, can be stored in a session or submit using method POST

hoped it helped

Comment: Sorry this isn't helpful. The problem isn't how to return data into pages, i'm using LIMIT to achieve this. The problem is how to work out which of these pages a given post id resides in.

Comment: since you show 5 posts per page and post on topic order weight is 16, its on the page 6 (3rd query) 15,20
16 weight ID of post in topic
/
5 post per page
= 
3.2 , rounded down gives 3
SELECT posts FROM topic WHERE topicid=1 LIMIT (5*3),(5*3+5)
not sure though just a thought